# SQL Syntax to Combine Tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, join

I have three MS Access tables.  They are `Income_Statements`, `Balance_Sheets` and `Cash_Flow_Statements`.  These tables all share the same primary keys.  It is a three field primary key that includes `Ticker`, `[Year]` and `Period`.  I want to combine all three of these tables without duplicating the primary key fields of course.  I have a date criteria that needs to be met also.  I need record to be displayed that is equal or previous to a date that I select from a `DateTimePicker` called `dtpDateSelection`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim year As String = dtpDateSelection.Value.Year
Dim quarter As String = ((dtpDateSelection.Value.Month - 1) \ 3) + 1

Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Ticker, [Year], Period, Income_Statements.Net_Income, Balance_Sheets.Total_Assets, Cash_Flow_Statements.Net_Cash_Flow_Operating FROM Income_Statements, Balance_Sheets, Cash_Flow_Statements WHERE Period < 5 AND Period <= #" & quarter & "# AND [Year] <= #" & year & "#", con)
Dim quarterlyReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
Dim Quarterly As New DataTable

Quarterly.Load(quarterlyReader)
DataGridViewScreen.DataSource = Quarterly
quarterlyReader.Close()
```

I'm having trouble with my `WHERE` statement.  How can I make this work?

Comment: hard to tell what you are doing without seeing how you parsed the DateTimePicker.  But it does seem like you might be missing a JOIN or two.

Comment: Could I do something like this: `"SELECT * FROM Income_Statements, Balance_Sheets, Cash_Flow_Statements WHERE Period < 5 AND Period <= #" & quarter & "# AND [Year] <= #" & year & "#"` with a `JOIN` statement somewhere?

Comment: You need a `JOIN` (ie "combine") and make use of those Primary Keys.  See Linger's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about joining the tables together and specifying the fields you want:

```
SELECT i.Ticker, i.[Year], i.Period, i.Net_Income, 
   b.Total_Assets, c.Net_Cash_Flow_Operating 
FROM (Income_Statements AS i 
   INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets AS b 
   ON (i.Ticker = b.Ticker) AND (i.[Year] = b.[Year]) AND (i.Period = b.Period)) 
   INNER JOIN Cash_Flow_Statements AS c 
   ON (b.Ticker = c.Ticker) AND (b.[Year] = c.[Year]) AND (b.Period = c.Period)
WHERE i.Period <= #" & quarter & "# 
   AND i.[Year] <= #" & year & "#"
```

Comment: That works great!  Is there anyway to incorporate a * (select fields from the tables) in this?

Comment: You can incorporate whatever fields you want, you could use `SELECT i.*, b.*, c.*` if you want to pull every field from all three tables.

Answer (score 3):

Your WHERE clause is treating the Period column in two ways - as an integer and as a Date (that's what the hash symbols imply) and it can't be both.

Comment: That's great!  That cleared up the first error message.  The other one I'm getting is `The specified field 'Ticker' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.`  How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to specify which table at the least

Comment: You need to prefix it with a table name to resolve the ambiguity, so Income_Statements.Ticker should work.